# OpenGL ES: Is it more efficient to use glClear or use glDrawArrays with primitives that render over used frames?

Tags: performance, opengl-es

For example, if I have several figures rendered over a black background, is it more efficient to call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` each frame, or render black triangles over artifacts from the past frame? I would think that rendering black triangles over artifacts would be faster, since less pixels need to be changed than clearing the entire screen. However, I have also read online that some drivers and graphics hardware perform optimizations when using `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` that cannot occur when rendering black triangles instead.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things you neglected which will probably change how you look at this:

- Painting over the top with triangles doesn't play well with depth testing.  So you have to disable testing first.
- Painting over the top with triangles has to be strictly ordered with the previous result.  While `glClear` breaks data dependencies, allowing out of order execution to start drawing the next frame as long as there's enough memory for both framebuffers to exist independently.
- Double-buffering, to avoid tearing effects, uses multiple framebuffers anyway.  So to use the result of the prior frame as a starting point for the new one, not only do you have to wait for the prior frame to finish rendering, you also have to copy its framebuffer into the buffer for the new frame.  Which requires touching every pixel.
- In a single buffering scenario, drawing over the top of the previous frame requires not only finishing rendering, but finishing streaming it to the display device.  Which leaves you only the blanking interval to render the entire new frame.  That almost certainly will prevent achieving maximum frame rate.

Generally, clearing touches every pixel just as copying does, but doesn't require flushing the pipeline.  So it's much better to start a frame by `glFlush`.